# how to change an element in a map and get its location?

Tags: c++, stl, std

when I have a std::map, is there an elegant way to at the same time:

1. insert / edit an element given its key
2. get an iterator to the inserted element

The best way I found that prevent doing 2 look-up in the map is:

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;
//do some stuff with the map
std::map<int,int>::iterator  it = myMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0,0)).first;
it->second = 0; //necessary because insert does not overwrite the values
```

Is it possible to do both of those things in a single statement / line?
thanks

Comment: Note that the map's value type is not `pair<int, int>`, but rather `pair<const int, int>`.

Comment: Insert or edit, which one do you want? Clearly you already have a one-liner for insertion, so what exactly is the question?

Comment: I believe you have found the most efficient way.  If you just don't like the look of it, implement a `replace` function that combines the two steps, but even that will be implemented in terms of your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, the STL functions and containers don't always do what you'd expect. Here are two generic versions, the first more like your code above:

```
template<class Map>
inline typename Map::iterator ForceInsert1( 
    Map&                           m, 
    const typename Map::key_type&  k, 
    const typename Map::data_type& d )
{
    typename Map::iterator it = m.insert( 
        typename Map::value_type( k, d ) ).first;
    it->second = d; // only necessary if the key already exists
    return it;
}

template<class Map>
inline typename Map::iterator ForceInsert2( 
    Map&                           m, 
    const typename Map::key_type&  k, 
    const typename Map::data_type& d )
{
    typename Map::iterator it = m.find( k );
    if( it != m.end() )
    {
        it->second = d;
    }
    else
    {
        it = m.insert( typename Map::value_type( k, d ) ).first;
    }
    return it;
}

typedef std::map<int, int> MyMap;
void Foo( MyMap& myMap )
{
    ForceInsert1( myMap, 42, 100 );
    ForceInsert2( myMap, 64, 128 );
}
```

Comment: what does the typename Map::data_type() do? is that the default constructor?

Comment: It is (or was -- I changed it). The data_type is only required to be default-constructable if you use the [] operator. The assignment, as the new comment notes, is only required if the key already exists. Otherwise, insert does in fact set the data associated with the inserted key.

Comment: Better would be to use std::lower_bound in ForceInsert2 and then supply that as the hint for insertion. See Scott Meyers's "Effective STL" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
map<int, int> m;
map<int, int>::iterator iter;
(iter = (m.insert(make_pair(1,1))).first)->second = 5;
```

Obviously the second value in `make_pair` is irrelevant (as long as it is of the right type).  Here you set the value the iterator points to to 5.

To be a bit cheeky, technically this would also be one statement:

```
iter = myMap.insert(make_pair(0,0)).first, iter->second = 0;
```

the comma (`,`) operator guarantees that all side effects take place before the rhs is evaluated, so `iter` has the right value

Comment: Alright, this would work. But I still find it annoying that you need make one useless copy of the 2nd type (the "1") for this to work. Obviously this isn't a big deal with ints, but what about bigger structures?

Comment: When the structure is big enough that making copies more than once is a problem, you might be better of `find`-ing the key first and inserting only if necessary (you could create a template function to do this if you need to use the logic many times).  As it is, you are making a copy for the `pair`, then insert only copies again if it actually inserts (which you need to anyway).  So the suggested version makes at most tree copies, while you need at least two anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the value and not the pair:

```
int& value = myMap[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myMap[0] = 0;
```

This line will insert a value with a key of 0 if it does not exist, and in either case it will set the value for that key to 0.

This is roughly similar to what you had, which can be made into a single line:

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0,0)).first->second = 0;
```

Comment: Yeah but I would also like to return an iterator to the inserted element