# How to get an element in a map and change it

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

How to get an element in a map and change it? For example, if I have:

```
{'a', 100},  {'b', 200},  {'c', 300},  {'d', 400},  {'e', 500}
```

I want to get to the value of `'a'` and change it from `100` to `105`.

Comment: With `std::map<char,int>` you can simply use the `[]` operator and assignment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And if my key is an Object?

Comment: Then your "object" needs to fulfill the requirements for `std::map` key types.

Comment: By using Iterators check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148015/16962816

Comment: Note that `char` instances are also objects, in C++.  (And they are also primitives.)

Comment: @Xavi It doesn't matter what it is. `table[key] = value;` assigns a new value for the key `key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map<char, int>::iterator it = m.find('a'); 
if (it != m.end() {
    it->second = 105;
```

Comment: Or `if (auto it = m.find('a'); it != m.end()) { it->second = 105; }`.